# Matrix of values as parameter for a macro

Tags: macros

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcommand{\values}[2]{
    \ifcase#1%
        \ifcase#2%
            value a%
        \c%
            value b%
        \or%
            value c%
        \fi
    \or%
        \ifcase#2%
            value d%
        \or%
            value e%
        \or%
            value f%
        \fi
    \fi%
}

\newcounter{ct}
\newcommand{\mytable}[1]{
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
        First & Second & Third
        \forloop{ct}{0}{\value{ct} < #1}{
            \\ \hline
            \values{\thect}{0} & \values{\thect}{1} & \values{\thect}{2}
        }
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
    \mytable{2}
    \mytable{3}
\end{document}
```

What I want to do is to define a macro `\mytable`, which takes the number of rows as first argument, and then a second argument which provides the content of the table. My current approach uses a second macro for providing the content. I am searching for a way to pass the values currently defined in `\values` to `\mytable`, so that the second call can have a different content. `\renewcommand{\values}` between the calls isn't an option in the actual code.

Comment: Would something like `\mytable{a,b,c;d,e,f}` suffice?

Comment: No, the call to `\mytable` and the definition of the values need to be at different places in my code.

Comment: So `\mytable{2}` will just use the first two rows defined beforehand?

Comment: I want to call it like `\mytable{2}{\values}` and then again with `\mytable{3}{\othervalues}`, where each builds a table with the values that have been passed as content

Comment: It seems to me that egreg's initial suggestion gives you both "2" and the `\values` in a single argument.  I'm not sure why it can't work in your case.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Because I need to define the values at one source file and the call to `\mytables` macro is in another source file. The file with the values is a customizable configuration file where the values can be changed; the call to `\mytables` is inside the document structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still not clear what flexibility you need in setting the values, but here is one possibility that may or may not suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcommand{\valuesA}[2]{
    \ifcase#1%
        \ifcase#2%
            value a%
        \or%
            value b%
        \or%
            value c%
        \fi
    \or%
        \ifcase#2%
            value d%
        \or%
            value e%
        \or%
            value f%
        \fi
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\valuesB}[2]{
    \ifcase#1%
        \ifcase#2%
            value A%
        \or%
            value B%
        \or%
            value C%
        \fi
    \or%
        \ifcase#2%
            value X%
        \or%
            value Y%
        \or%
            value Z%
        \fi
    \fi%
}

\newcounter{ct}
\newcommand{\mytable}[2]{
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
        First & Second & Third
        \forloop{ct}{0}{\value{ct} < #1}{
            \\ \hline
            #2{\thect}{0} & #2{\thect}{1} & #2{\thect}{2}
        }
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
    \mytable{2}{\valuesA}

\bigskip
    \mytable{3}{\valuesB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well that was simple. I should have just tried that before asking. Thanks!

Comment: @flyx Glad I could be of some assistance.

Comment: The mess is in the first column. Is it desired?

Comment: @wipet - Thanks.  One of the `\or` in the first columns got scrogged in the copy/paste as `\c` resulting in the mess.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

With `xparse` and `expl3` you can have a better interface for defining the matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definematrix}{O{default}m}
 {
  \flyx_define_matrix:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usematrix}{O{default}m}
 {
  \flyx_use_matrix:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setmatrixformat}{mm}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_flyx_matrix_format_tl { #1 }
  \tl_gset:Nn \g_flyx_matrix_header_tl { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_flyx_temp_rows_seq
\int_new:N \l_flyx_row_index_int
\tl_new:N \g_flyx_matrix_format_tl
\tl_new:N \g_flyx_matrix_header_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \flyx_define_matrix:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_flyx_temp_rows_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \int_zero:N \l_flyx_row_index_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_flyx_temp_rows_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_flyx_row_index_int
    \tl_gclear_new:c { g_flyx_#1_matrix_ \int_to_roman:n { \l_flyx_row_index_int } _tl }
    \tl_gset:cn
     { g_flyx_#1_matrix_ \int_to_roman:n { \l_flyx_row_index_int } _tl }
     { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \flyx_use_matrix:nn #1 #2
 {
  \use:x { \exp_not:N \begin{tabular} { \exp_not:V \g_flyx_matrix_format_tl } }
  \hline
  \tl_use:N \g_flyx_matrix_header_tl \\
  \hline
  \tl_clear:N \l_flyx_table_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nv \l_flyx_table_body_tl { g_flyx_#1_matrix_ \int_to_roman:n { ##1 } _tl }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_flyx_table_body_tl { \\ }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_flyx_table_body_tl
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right:Nn { Nv }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\definematrix{
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i
}

\definematrix[numbers]{
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4 \\
  5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8
}

\setmatrixformat{|l|l|l|}{First & Second & Third}

\begin{document}

\usematrix{2} \quad \usematrix{3}

\medskip

\setmatrixformat{lll}{A & B & C}

\usematrix{2}

\medskip

\setmatrixformat{cc}{A & B}

\usematrix[numbers]{3} \qquad \usematrix[numbers]{4}

\end{document}
```

The `\definematrix` has an optional argument (a name); successive declarations with the same name (or without name) will overwrite the defined matrix.

With `\setmatrixformat` you set the columns and the header to be used from that point on.

With `\usematrix` you can specify a name (or use the default matrix) and the number of rows to use.

[image]